# XSLT - Match element with multiple child elements

Tags: xslt, templates, element, design-patterns

`<xsl:template match="element[child]">`
The above works. What is the real syntax for the following pseudo-syntax? :
`<xsl:template match="element[child1 AND child2]">`

In the place on `AND`:

- `and` doesn't work
- `&` doesn't work
- `,` doesn't work

What is it?

Thanks.

Comment: `element[child1 and child2]` should work. How did you test it? http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#booleans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
element[child1][child2]
```

From Michael Kay's latest XSLT/XPath 2.0 reference:

> Each predicate is applied to the
>   sequence in turn; only those items in
>   the sequence for which the predicate
>   is true pass through to the next
>   stage. The final result consists of
>   those items in the original sequence
>   that satisfy eadh of the predicates,
>   retaining their original order.

(Page 638)

Comment: I also had to do `priority="1"` to give it precedence over `element[child1]` and `element[child2]`.